# Impossible to install a shared library

Tags: shared-libraries

I've installed Pyaudio by doing like described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio).

Even though I've set the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and ran the sudo `ldconfig`
the Python script raises:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "/home/IoTree/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: libportaudio.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here's my two last lines on `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib: /home/IoTree/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages /
```

When I use the command to find the directory where `libportaudio.so` is located by doing like so: `find -name "libportaudio.so"` I got

```
./home/IoTree/portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.so
./usr/local/lib/libportaudio.so
./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libportaudio.so
```

Which means it exists but it is probably badly written in the `~/.bashrc`.

Can someone help me on this? I've been struggling for 3 days now...

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be spaces between `/usr/local/lib: /home/IoTree/` and between `site-packages /` just a colon, I think. The spaces look wrong in the  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` line

That is to say:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib: /home/IoTree/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages /
                                                    ^^                    and                       ^^
```

So the lines should be:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/home/IoTree/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages:/
```

Then again:

- why is there a `/` at the end?
- why is `/usr/local/lib` in the path twice?

The paths that you should use are

```
/home/IoTree/portaudio/lib/.libs/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
```

So try

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/IoTree/portaudio/lib/.libs:/home/IoTree/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I'm not even sure if `/home/IoTree/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` is required, so this might suffice:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/IoTree/portaudio/lib/.libs
```

Comment: You're welcome :-) Don't forget to upvote and accept (using the green tick) any answers that you found to be useful